# Replacement for clipRect() while using hardware acceleration

Tags: android, hardware-acceleration

Can someone advice some replacement for clipRect(). clip* methods aren't implemented for hardware acceleration yet

Answer (score 2):

clipRect() is implemented and works just fine as long as you use the default Op or use the Union or Replace op.